# Generalization of a proposition of linear map to infinite case

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

My textbook says that Proposition 2 can be considered as a generalization of Proposition 1 to an infinite case. I don't understand the above statement, although I understand the proofs of both propositions. Could anybody help me understand the relation between the two propositions?

**Proposition 1:**

> Let $V$ and $W$ be $K$-linear spaces, and $x_{1}, \ldots x_{n}\in V$
>   be basis of $V$. For any $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n) \in W^n$, there
>   exists a linear map $f: V \to W$ which satisfies $f(x_i) = y_i$ for
>   all $i\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

**Proposition 2:**

> Define $K^{(X)} = \{f: X \to K| \#\{x \in X|f(x)\neq0 \}\neq \infty\}$, which is a linear space. Define $e_x \in K^{(X)}$ such that for
>   $x, y\in X$, $e_{x}(y) = 1$ if $x=y$ and else, $e_{x}(y) = 0$. Let $V$ be
>   a $K$-linear space. Define a map
>   $F:\{\mathrm{Linear\,\,map\,}K^{(X)}\to V \}\ni f \to g\in\{map\, X
>  \to V\}$ where $g(x) = f(e_{x})$. Then, $F$ is a bijective map.

(I must say that the statement and propositions are translated to English from my native language, and I hope my English is not that bad.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposition $1$ states that, if $V$ is vector space with dimension $n$, i.e. if  $V\simeq K^n$, we have a *surjective*  map
\begin{align}
\mathscr L(V,W)&\mathrel{—}\twoheadrightarrow W^n\simeq W^{\mathcal B},\\
f &\longmapsto (f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n).
\end{align}
where $\mathcal B=\{x_1 \dots,x_n\}$ denotes a (finite) basis for $V.

Sticking to the same naming conventions as in Proposition $1$, Proposition $2$ asserts that for any vector space $V$ with (not necessarily finite) basis $\mathcal B$ and any vector space $W$, we have a *bijective* map
\begin{align}
\mathscr L(V,W)&\overset{\sim}{\;\mathrel{—}\longrightarrow} W^{\mathcal B},\\
f &\longmapsto \bigl(f(x)\bigr)_{x\in \mathcal B}
\end{align}

In other words, the second proposition says a little more than the first:  a linear map from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $W$ is entirely determined by the images in $W$  of the vectors of a basis of $V$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me the definition of $W^{\mathcal B}$?

Comment: The set of maps from $\mathcal B$ to $W$ (as sets!).